# Is there a tool that will optimize mathematical formulas?

Tags: java, c++, c, optimization

I recently came across an issue:
I had to do some complex math in a program. A friend noticed it was running slow and told me the compution of the result could be improved by some simple rearangements in the formula. Something like this:

```
1/15 * x = x/15
or
2*x + 2*y = 2*(x + y)
```

I know these were simple ones. So I have a more complex example:
My CAS gave me this formula:

```
-1/10*v+1/15*(3*v^2+60*s)^(1/2)
```

I put this in Java:

```
(Math.sqrt(3.0 * (v*v + 20.0*s))/15.0) - (v/10.0)
```

This is a huge improvement. But I am pretty sure this could be optimized even further by some other simple optimizations.
I came up with some other equivalent formulas. But how do I know which is the fastest *(whithout profiling of course. Everybody could do that and it takes an awful lot of time)*.
*(It should be obvious that the last one is the fastest.)*

```
((2.0 * Math.sqrt(3.0 * (v*v + 20.0*s))) - (3.0 * v))/30.0
((3.4641016151377544 * Math.sqrt(v*v + 20.0*s)) - (3.0 * v))/30.0
((3.4641016151377544 * Math.sqrt(v*v + 20.0*s)) - (3.0 * v)) * 0.03333333333333333
(Math.sqrt(v*v + 20.0*s) - (0.8660254037844387 * v)) * 0.11547005383792515
```

I really brought the above formula to the limit *(Rearranging the formula to get rid of uneccesary operations and precalculating some constants... Really not easy at all!)*. This was all done by hand and some Math knowledge. In addition, I honestly doubt that any compiler or interpreter (Java and other runtime interpreted languages) would be able to convert `(Math.sqrt(3.0 * (v*v + 20.0*s))/15.0) - (v/10.0)` to this much faster formula `(Math.sqrt(v*v + 20.0*s) - (0.8660254037844387 * v)) * 0.11547005383792515`, which will give the exact same result...
This is a lot of work that takes a lot of time. Especially if there are several hundereds of formulas.
There are in fact many small changes you could do to a formula some of them could really help improve the compution speed.

Is there something like a tool that will optimize such formulas for C/C++/Java code?

*(If more examples are needed I will provide more)*

***(Assuming floating point operations in all calculations. I just wanted to make the formulas stay easy readable)***

Comment: Um, most decent compilers will already perform such optimisations for you automatically. I wouldn't try to hand-optimise them unless it's a non-obvious strength-reduction optimisation. Certainly, the examples you gave are trivial for a compiler to optimise.

Comment: It is called [symbolic computation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_computation) & [computer algebra systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) (see also [a comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_computer_algebra_systems) ...) simplification of mathematical forumulae is undecidable in the general case.

Comment: It's called a "programmer" ;-) Seriously though, the optimizer will do some things for you where the results are *guaranteed* identical. Where they aren't, changes like this can affect the numerical stability of your algorithm, so you shouldn't automate applying them in the name of efficiency or you'll break someone's slow but correct code. In C etc, `1 / 15 * x` isn't even approximately equivalent to `x / 15` anyway, although if you'd said `15.0` they're pretty close.

Comment: Try Numerical Recipes: http://www.nr.com/

Comment: And you should profile your program.

Comment: [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination) is an example of an optimisation that the compiler does for you. there are many more and your cases are most likely covered too.

Comment: You commented that you didn't profile it and seem to be against it for some reason. But if you didn't profile it, how or why do you suspect this one math statement is a bottleneck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a classic book called [Numerical Recipes](http://www.nr.com/).

Efficiency of math equations may not be to implement their simplest form.

Example: z = 2*x + 2*y;
As given, there are two multiply operations and one addition operation.

Using distributive property, this can be rewritten as:
z = 2 * (x + y);

Now there is only one multiply operation.

In general, the operations are ranked below in order of fastest to slowest:

- addition
- subtraction -- requires negation before addition (thus one extra
  operation)
- multiplication  -- Could be a shift, but most likely a combination of
  shift and add.
- division
  Math calculations that can be rearranged according to the above will be more efficient.

Other techniques include loop unrolling (executing many statements before restarting the loop) and data setup (load all data before processing).

Comment: I know that the simplest form my not be the most efficent. But is there a simple way *(or tool)* to automate this process? I mean it can't be that hard to do some basic changes that are known to be faster. Meaning rewritting the formula using more of the faster operations like addition and subtraction.

Comment: "basic changes that are known to be faster" the compiler does them for you.

Comment: Review the Numerical Recipes website.  They may have some links to tools or projects.

Comment: I didn't find anything... (I might just have overlooked it...)